# TypeScrpt | Как мне использовать в .js функции .ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript

В файле `.ts` у меня есть функция, которая принимает два параметра, оба типа `number`. Она возвращает сумму этих двух параметров. А в `.js` файле я запрашиваю `.ts` файл. Дело в том, что в `JS` неудобно писать перед каждой функцией

```js
/** *@params {number} a
    *@params {number} b
*/
```

Можно ли мне через `JavaScript` файл вызвать мою функцию на `TypeScript`? Мой код на TS:

```
export const Foo = (a: number, b: number) => {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: `.d.ts` - TS файл деклараций для JS. Например [в песочнице](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGIQnAvHACgEMAuOZAVwFsAjYKAGjhrMtvoEo8A+OAbwBQcYXCjAYFKMjhE4AamYBuAQF8gA) справа кнопка "JS
.D.TS
Errors
Logs
Plugins"

Comment: [доки](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html#dts-files)

Comment: Возможно, стоит посмотреть на флаг allowjs в файле настроек тс

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы это сделать - Вам придется компилировать весь Ваш проект с помощью typescript.

Сделал небольшой пример, код в песочницу запихнуть не удалось - поэтому вот ссылка на git:

https://github.com/gayratv/js-call-ts

Привел два направления - вызов из js ts и широко известная - вызов из ts js

Собственно основной рецепт - это параметр в tsconfig.json
"allowJs": true